# Working with unix date format and $ meaning

Tags: unix

I have to yet understand how variables in unix works. Im trying to print current Hour and multiple it by 60 ( If now is 1 AM it would print 60)

my code looks like this

`date +"$((%H*2))"` but this just doest throw result 60 but just ((1*60)) how can i achieve the result 60? Also what is the meaning of $ in shell?

Answer (score 3):

For clarity, I would do this in two steps:

```
cur_hour=$(date +"%H")
result=$(( cur_hour * 60 ))
```

`$( ... )` is for [command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution).
`$(( ... ))` is for [arithmetic expressions](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression).

---

You could do it in one go, but it may be harder to understand at first glance:

```
result=$(( $(date +"%H") * 60 ))
```